# Not able to launch the browser using Spec Flow with CodedUi

Tags: coded-ui-tests, specflow

Trying to Launch the browser using 
BrowserWindow browser = BrowserWindow.Launch();
getting exception in Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate

I have included following dll :

*TechTalk.SpecFlow*, *nunit.util* , *nunit.core* , *Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework* , *NUnit.VisualStudio.TestAdapter* , *nunit.core.interfaces* , *nunit.framework* ,
*Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting*

and Created test method using **Spec flow with coded UI** getting runtime exception:

***Test method specflow_CodedUI.SpecFlowFeature1Feature.AddTwoNumbers threw exception: 
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Playback, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.***

Comment: clean and then rebuild, but this time click EXTRA hard!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try cleaning your solution, and deleting your packages folder and then rebuilding - I had a similar issue some time ago, doing this fixed it.

Obviously, if you require an assembly binding redirect for your Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting reference, make sure it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

It does not work directly as specflow does not generate `[CodedUITest]` attribute on the unit tests. Follow this: https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Using-SpecFlow-with-CodedUI-API

Answer (score 0):

I have been using `Process.Start` to start the browser:

```
public class Browser : IDisposable
{
    private System.Diagnostics.Process currentBrowserProcess;

    private BrowserWindow window;

    public BrowserWindow Window
    {
        get
        {
            if (window == null)
            {
                window = BrowserWindow.FromProcess(currentBrowserProcess);
                window.CloseOnPlaybackCleanup = false;
            }

            return window;
        }
    }

    public Browser(string url)
    {
        Open(url);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Window.Close();
        window = null;
        currentBrowserProcess = null;
    }

    public void Open(string url)
    {
        if (currentBrowserProcess == null)
        {
            currentBrowserProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("iexplore.exe", string.Format("\"{0}\"", url));
        }
        else
        {
            Window.NavigateToUrl(new Uri(url));
        }
    }
}
```

And to use it:

```
Browser browser = new Browser("http://localhost/foo");
```

You can put that in the `ScenarioContext` for safe keeping. You can access the "window" object of the browser using `browser.Window`. Add your own helper methods to this class to make finding elements easy.

```
public HtmlButton Button(string buttonText, UITestControl container = null)
{
    HtmlButton element = new HtmlButton(container ?? Body);
    element.FilterProperties[HtmlButton.PropertyNames.InnerText] = buttonText;
    return element;
}
```

And to use:

```
HtmlButton button = browser.Button("Click Me!");

Mouse.Click(button);
```